# Yolo-v3 tiny *.weights file contains less weights then expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, yolo

I build a Yolo V3 Tiny model in Tensorflow and I would like to load the weights provided by [Yolo](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3-tiny.weights) itself. I found [here](https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2/blob/master/utils.py) and reading the official Yolo code, that I can read yolov3-tiny.weights discarding the first 16 bytes and then reading the remaining bytes converting them in float32.

Now, yolov3-tiny.weights has 35.434.956 bytes, so (35.434.956-16)/4=8.858.735 float32 numbers and so I should have 8.858.735 weights.

Anyway the summary of my yolov3-tiny network is the following:

```
>>> model.summary()
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
Input (InputLayer)               [(None, 416, 416, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_1 (Conv2D)                 (None, 416, 416, 16) 448         Input[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
norm_1 (BatchNormalizationV1)   (None, 416, 416, 16) 64          conv_1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 208, 208, 16) 0           norm_1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_2 (Conv2D)                 (None, 208, 208, 32) 4640        max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
norm_2 (BatchNormalizationV1)   (None, 208, 208, 32) 128         conv_2[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 104, 104, 32) 0           norm_2[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_3 (Conv2D)                 (None, 104, 104, 64) 18496       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
norm_3 (BatchNormalizationV1)   (None, 104, 104, 64) 256         conv_3[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 52, 52, 64)   0           norm_3[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_4 (Conv2D)                 (None, 52, 52, 128)  73856       max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
norm_4 (BatchNormalizationV1)   (None, 52, 52, 128)  512         conv_4[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 26, 26, 128)  0           norm_4[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_5 (Conv2D)                 (None, 26, 26, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
norm_5 (BatchNormalizationV1)   (None, 26, 26, 256)  1024        conv_5[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 13, 13, 256)  0           norm_5[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_6 (Conv2D)                 (None, 13, 13, 512)  1180160     max_pooling2d_4[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
norm_6 (BatchNormalizationV1)   (None, 13, 13, 512)  2048        conv_6[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 13, 13, 512)  0           norm_6[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_7 (Conv2D)                 (None, 13, 13, 1024) 4719616     max_pooling2d_5[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
norm_7 (BatchNormalizationV1)   (None, 13, 13, 1024) 4096        conv_7[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_8 (Conv2D)                 (None, 13, 13, 256)  262400      norm_7[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
norm_8 (BatchNormalizationV1)   (None, 13, 13, 256)  1024        conv_8[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_11 (Conv2D)                (None, 13, 13, 128)  32896       norm_8[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
norm_10 (BatchNormalizationV1)  (None, 13, 13, 128)  512         conv_11[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)               (None, 26, 26, 128)  0           norm_10[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 26, 26, 384)  0           lambda_1[0][0]                   
                                                                 norm_5[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_9 (Conv2D)                 (None, 13, 13, 512)  1180160     norm_8[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_12 (Conv2D)                (None, 26, 26, 256)  884992      concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
norm_9 (BatchNormalizationV1)   (None, 13, 13, 512)  2048        conv_9[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
norm_11 (BatchNormalizationV1)  (None, 26, 26, 256)  1024        conv_12[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_10 (Conv2D)                (None, 13, 13, 255)  130815      norm_9[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_13 (Conv2D)                (None, 26, 26, 255)  65535       norm_11[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)                 (None, 507, 85)      0           conv_10[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)               (None, 2028, 85)     0           conv_13[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 2535, 85)     0           lambda[0][0]                     
                                                                 lambda_2[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 8,861,918
Trainable params: 8,855,550
Non-trainable params: 6,368
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

and has 8.861.918 weights. There are (8.861.918-8.858.735)=3183 parameters more then those contained in yolov3-tiny.weights. Had I make any error building the network or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For every `conv layer` with batch-normalization, you mistake using `bias(b)`. In `yolo`, `conv layer` followed by `batchnorm` don't have bias. For example, for `conv_1 layer`, the correct para number should be `3*3*3*16=432`, while in your model, it's `432+16=448`.